# Вылетает ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyttsx3

Вкратце: Создал файл main.py и через pip установил pyttsx3. Скомпилировал в Exe, причем после компиляции в exe вылетает стек ошибок:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
File "lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 46, in init
File "lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 52, in __init__
File "lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 75, in __init__
File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 936, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3.drivers'
[3408] Failed to execute script main
```

Кто знает - помогите плиз. Очень нужно.

Comment: Возможно тот модуль pyttsx3 не был подхвачен и добавлен в exe, в таких случая вручную указываются модули. Укажите в теге вопроса, чем вы в exe собирали

Comment: модулем pyinstaller

Answer (score 3):

Я тоже столкнулся с этой проблемой. И нашёл решение!
Вводи вот этот код и название файла.

> pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers
> --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.dummy --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.espeak --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.nsss --hidden-import=pyttsx3.drivers.sapi5 Имяфайла.py